# Pyspark Write DStream data to Elasticsearch using saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to transform the Kafka Stream into RDDs and insert these RDDs into an Elasticsearch database. This is my code:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("ola")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) 
es_write_conf = {
    "es.nodes": "localhost",
    "es.port": "9200",
    "es.resource": "pipe/word"
}

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)
brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:]
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers}) 
lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])  
value_counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)

value_counts.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.map(f))
value_counts.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
    path='-',
    outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
    conf=es_write_conf)

ssc.start()  
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile function should write those RDDs to ES. However I get this error:

```
   value_counts.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
   AttributeError: 'TransformedDStream' object has no attribute 'saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile'
```

The transform functions should be able to convert the stream to Spark dataframes. How can I write these RDD into Elasticsearch? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreachRDD`:

```
value_counts.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(...))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! However, now i got a giant error:6/12/29 19:23:06 WARN EsOutputFormat: Speculative execution enabled for reducer - consider disabling it to prevent data corruption
16/12/29 19:23:06 WARN EsOutputFormat: Cannot determine task id
16/12/29 19:23:07 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 83.0 (TID 55)
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: Found unrecoverable error [127.0.0.1:9200] returned Bad Request(400) - failed to parse;Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes; Bailing out..

Comment: I am not familiar with ES so I won't be any help here. Does it work when you save a single RDD manually?

Answer (score 0):

```
new = rawUser.rdd.map(lambda item: ('key', {'id': item['entityId'],'targetEntityId': item['targetEntityId']}))
```

> rawUser is DATAFRAME and
>   new is PipelinedRDD

```
new.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
    path='/home/aakash/test111/', 
    outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", 
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", 
    conf={ "es.resource" : "index/test" ,"es.mapping.id":"id","es.nodes" : "localhost","es.port" : "9200","es.nodes.wan.only":"false"})
```

**Most important thing here is download proper compatible JAR
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop
check version of elastic and download proper jar.**

Command to make pyspark use jar.
`pyspark --jars elasticsearch-hadoop-6.2.4.jar`